# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence when calling numpy.save()

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, deep-learning, numpy-ndarray

I have a list called `training_data` that I'd like to store in an `.npy` file.
Each element of the list contains a `480x270` image matrix `screen` and a `1x4` `output` list; So an element would look like so:

```py
[screen,output]
```

Essentially, I'm storing an image and the action taken(the key pressed-out of 4 available options) at the instant that the image was captured from the screen to train a CNN.

While in the list format, `training_data` stores all my records without any issues, so this works:

```py
training_data.append([screen,output])
```

But, when I try to save the list as a numpy array, into a `.npy` file, like so:

```py
np.save(file_name,training_data)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions. The detected shape was (1000, 2) + inhomogeneous part.
```

I'm following a tutorial to create this CNN project. Admittedly, the tutorial was made a few years back (2017). Back then, the save operation worked flawlessly:

[Tutorial](https://youtu.be/watch?v=F4y4YOpUcTQ&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDeETZEOy4VdocT7TOjfSA8a&index=8%5C) `Timestamp: 17:49`

Any ideas as to why this error occurs will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: `training_data` is a list (of lists).  `np.save` tries to create an array from it.  THe error occurs during that conversion (at least that's my guess, since you forgot to provide the full error message (with traceback).  Working from video tutorials often has problems.  You need to match the tutorial exactly, including the data (at least data sizes).  And if you don't know basic python and numpy, you can't handle any sort of deviation.

Comment: `np.array(training_data)` should produce the same error.  Also pay attention to any VisibleDeprecationWarning

Comment: Indeed, the error seems to stem from the list to ndarray conversion. There is no VisibleDeprecationWarning, however. Is there something fundamentally wrong about converting this list to a np array?

Comment: If a list has elements that differ in shape, `numpy` can only make an object dtype array.  But for some combinations of shapes, it raises an error like this.

Comment: Have you considered using `pickle` instead?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion: indeed I have. However, according to some quick searches, pickle isn't as efficient in storing and loading arrays(especially really big ones) as the `.npy` format is. pickle does work flawlessly so far,though.

Comment: I think those searches exaggerate the differences.  `pickle` uses the `np.save` code to serialize a numpy array.  `np.save` uses `pickle` to serialize non-array objects (see the `allow_pickle` parameter). So unless your list can be turned into a float dtype multidimensional array, all the elements will be 'pickled'.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions! I'll switch to pickle